# Multicast delegates not defined error

Tags: vb.net

What is wrong with this code the MyEqaution is not defined and i dont know why can anyone help. It should be defined cause I defined right? Im so confused. Or did i not define MyEqaution the right way. Like I said can anybody help.

```
Imports System.Delegate

Module Module1

    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim Answer As Integer
    Dim MyEqaution As Math

    Private Delegate Sub Math()

    Sub Main()
        Dim MyEqaution As Math
        Dim ask As MyEqaution
        Dim Multiply1 As MyEqaution
        Dim Subtract1 As MyEqaution
        Dim Addition1 As MyEqaution
        Dim Divide1 As MyEqaution
        Dim MyEqationAll As Math

        ask = New MyEqaution(AddressOf Ask1)
        Multiply1 = New MyEqaution(AddressOf Multiply)
        Subtract1 = New MyEqaution(AddressOf Subtract)
        Addition1 = New MyEqaution(AddressOf Addition)
        Divide1 = New MyEqaution(AddressOf Divide)
        MyEqaution = Math.Combine(ask, Multiply1, Subtract1, Addition1, Divide1)
        MyEqationAll.DynamicInvoke("Math")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Sub Ask1()
        Console.WriteLine("Enter First Integer")
        a = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Second Integer")
        b = Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Sub Multiply()
        Answer = a * b
        Console.WriteLine(Answer)
    End Sub

    Sub Subtract()
        Answer = a - b
        Console.WriteLine(Answer)
    End Sub

    Sub Addition()
        Answer = a + b
        Console.WriteLine(Answer)
    End Sub

    Sub Divide()
        Answer = a / b
        Console.WriteLine(Answer)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Not to be rude, but, everything?

Comment: It's spelled "equation", FYI.

Comment: ok well im new so any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyEqaution is variable on your code

Dim statement usage:

```
Dim variable as Type
```

Here:

```
  Private Delegate Sub Math()
    Sub Main()

        'Dim ask As Math
        'Dim Multiply1 As Math
        'Dim Subtract1 As Math
        'Dim Addition1 As Math
        'Dim Divide1 As Math 
        'ask = New Math(AddressOf Ask1)
        'Multiply1 = New Math(AddressOf Multiply)
        'Subtract1 = New Math(AddressOf Subtract)
        'Addition1 = New Math(AddressOf Addition)
        'Divide1 = New Math(AddressOf Divide)
        'MyEqaution = CType(Math.Combine(ask, Multiply1, Subtract1, Addition1, Divide1), Math)
        'or shorter
         MyEqaution = CType(Math.Combine(New Math(AddressOf Ask1), New Math(AddressOf Multiply), _
                                    New Math(AddressOf Subtract), New Math(AddressOf Addition), New Math(AddressOf Divide)), Math)
        MyEqaution.Invoke()
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
```

Comment: i did that in my code and it didnt work did i define it wrong?

Comment: @naters302 check my answer.hope it be helpful