# Adding a multicast delegate to a VB.NET program

Tags: vb.net, math, delegates, console-application, multicastdelegate

For an assignment I was supposed to write a program that used delegates to do all four basic math functions at once. Which I did. Here is the code from that.

```
Module Module1
    Public Delegate Sub math(ByVal A As Integer, ByVal B As Integer)
    Dim A, B, C As Integer
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number")
        A = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine())
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter another number")
        B = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine())
        Dim objmath As New math(AddressOf add)
        objmath(A, B)
        add(A, B)
        objmath = New math(AddressOf multiply)
        objmath(A, B)
        multiply(A, B)
        objmath = New math(AddressOf subtract)
        subtract(A, B)
        subtract(A, B)
        objmath = New math(AddressOf divide)
        divide(A, B)
        divide(A, B)
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
    Sub add(ByVal A As Integer, ByVal B As Integer)
        C = A + B
        Console.WriteLine(C)
    End Sub
    Sub multiply(ByVal A As Integer, ByVal B As Integer)
        C = A * B
        Console.WriteLine(C)
    End Sub
    Sub subtract(ByVal A As Integer, ByVal B As Integer)
        C = A - B
        Console.WriteLine(C)
    End Sub
    Sub divide(ByVal A As Integer, ByVal B As Integer)
        C = A / B
        Console.WriteLine(C)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Now I have been asked to add a multicast delegate to this program that holds all four procedures and calls the procedures using the DynamicInvoke() method.  How and where in my program would I add that?

Comment: We're not here to do your homework.  *YOU* do it.  Show us some effort before you ask for help.

Comment: This is not homework. This is my work that I have done so far. My curriculum did not explain delegates very well and didn't explain multi-cast delegates at all. I am not asking for the answer, just clarifications and some examples with explanations. I am here to learn.

Comment: Students that attend your school have asked this question several times already.  There's [one here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20712319/multicast-delegates-not-defined-error/20712415#20712415) for example.